# Why I cannot compile with -fPIE but can with -fPIC?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, fpic, position-independent-code

I have one interesting compilation problem.
At first, please see code to be compiled.

```
$ ls
Makefile main.c sub.c sub.h
$ gcc -v
...
gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16) (GCC)
```

```
## Makefile
%.o: CFLAGS+=-fPIE #[2]

main.so: main.o sub.o
    $(CC) -shared -fPIC -o $@ $^
```

```c
//main.c
#include "sub.h"

int main_func(void){
    sub_func();
    subsub_func();

    return 0;
}
```

```c
//sub.h
#pragma once
void subsub_func(void);
void sub_func(void);
```

```c
//sub.c
#include "sub.h"
#include <stdio.h>
void subsub_func(void){
    printf("%s\n", __func__);
}
void sub_func(void){
    subsub_func();//[1]
    printf("%s\n", __func__);
}
```

And I compile this and got a error as below

```sh
$ LANG=en make
cc -fPIE   -c -o main.o main.c
cc -fPIE   -c -o sub.o sub.c
cc -shared -fPIC -o main.so main.o sub.o
/usr/bin/ld: sub.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `subsub_func' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main.so] Error 1
```

And after this, I modified the code(removing a line [1]/using -fPIC instead of -PIE[2]) and then successfully compiled these.

```sh
$ make #[1]
cc -fPIE   -c -o main.o main.c
cc -fPIE   -c -o sub.o sub.c
cc -shared -fPIC -o main.so main.o sub.o
$ make #[2]
cc -fPIC   -c -o main.o main.c
cc -fPIC   -c -o sub.o sub.c
cc -shared -fPIC -o main.so main.o sub.o
```

Why did this phenomenon happened?

I have heard that calling a function within an object is done through PLT when it is compiled with -fPIC but done by jumping to the function directly when it si compiled with -fPIE.
I guessed that the function call mechanism with -fPIE refrains from relocation.
But I would like to know exact and accurate explanation of that.

Would you help me?

Thank you, all.

Comment: FYI I have changed the yen signs in your code to backslashes, because I strongly suspect backslashes were intended in context.  Substitution of yen signs for backslashes is characteristic of a very old kludge (the Japanese national variant of ASCII) that I thought was long since extinct, but maybe not entirely? Are you writing from Japan?  Anyway, this doesn't affect the substance of your question, but it might have confused other readers who aren't as old as I am.

Comment: Thank you. I wrote this from Japan.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The *only* code generation difference between `-fPIC` and `-fPIE` for the code shown is in the call from `sub_func` to `subsub_func`.  With `-fPIC`, that call goes through the PLT; with `-fPIE`, it's a direct call.  In assembly dumps (`cc -S`), that looks like this:

```
--- sub.s.pic   2017-12-07 08:10:00.308149431 -0500
+++ sub.s.pie   2017-12-07 08:10:08.408068650 -0500
@@ -34,7 +34,7 @@ sub_func:
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
-   call    subsub_func@PLT
+   call    subsub_func
    leaq    __func__.2258(%rip), %rsi
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdi
    movl    $0, %eax
```

In unlinked object files, it's a change of relocation type:

```
--- sub.o.dump.pic  2017-12-07 08:13:54.197775840 -0500
+++ sub.o.dump.pie  2017-12-07 08:13:54.197775840 -0500
@@ -22,7 +22,7 @@
   1f:  55                      push   %rbp
   20:  48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   23:  e8 00 00 00 00          callq  28 <sub_func+0x9>
-           24: R_X86_64_PLT32  subsub_func-0x4
+           24: R_X86_64_PC32   subsub_func-0x4
   28:  48 8d 35 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rsi        # 2f <sub_func+0x10>
            2b: R_X86_64_PC32   .rodata+0x14
   2f:  48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi        # 36 <sub_func+0x17>
```

And, on this architecture, when you link a shared library using `cc -shared`, the linker does not allow the input object files to contain `R_X86_64_PC32` relocations targeting global symbols, thus the error you observed when you used `-fPIE` instead of `-fPIC`.

Now, you are probably wondering *why* direct calls within a shared library are not allowed.  In fact, they *are* allowed, but only when the callee is not a global.  For instance, if you declared `subsub_func` with `static`, then the call target would be resolved by the assembler and there would be no relocation at all in the object file, and if you declared it with `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))` then you would get an `R_X86_64_PC32` relocation but the linker would allow it because the callee is no longer exported from the library.  But in both cases `subsub_func` would not be callable from outside the library anymore.

*Now* you're probably wondering what it is about global symbols that means you have to call them through the PLT from a shared library.  This has to do with an aspect of the ELF symbol resolution rules that you may find surprising: any global symbol in a shared library can be *overridden* by either the executable, or an earlier library in the link order.  Concretely, if we leave your `sub.h` and `sub.c` alone but make `main.c` read like this:

```
//main.c
#include "sub.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void subsub_func(void) {
    printf("%s (main)\n", __func__);
}

int main(void){
    sub_func();
    subsub_func();

    return 0;
}
```

so it's now got the an official executable entry point in it but also a second definition of `subsub_func`, and we compile `sub.c` into a shared library and `main.c` into an executable that calls it, and run the whole thing, like this

```
$ cc -fPIC -c sub.c -o sub.o
$ cc -c main.c -o main.o
$ cc -shared -Wl,-soname,libsub.so.1 sub.o -o libsub.so.1
$ ln -s libsub.so.1 libsub.so
$ cc main.o -o main -L. -lsub
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main
```

the output will be

```
subsub_func (main)
sub_func
subsub_func (main)
```

That is, *both* the call from `main` to `subsub_func`, and the call from `sub_func`, within the library, to `subsub_func`, were resolved to the definition in the executable.  For that to be possible, the call from `sub_func` must go through the PLT.

You can change this behavior with an additional linker switch, [`-Bsymbolic`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-_002dBsymbolic).

```
$ cc -shared -Wl,-soname,libsub.so.1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic sub.o -o libsub.so.1
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main
subsub_func
sub_func
subsub_func (main)
```

Now the call from `sub_func` is resolved to the definition within the library.  In this case, using `-Bsymbolic` allows `sub.c` to be compiled with `-fPIE` instead of `-fPIC`, but I don't recommend you do that.  There are other effects of using `-fPIE` instead of `-fPIC`, such as changing how access to [thread-local storage](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/tls.pdf) needs to be done, and those cannot be worked around with `-Bsymbolic`.

Comment: I want to point out that this `-Wl,-Bsymbolic` flag is the only way for a C99 library I'm building to be built correctly in `gcc` from a CMake project. `clang` had no such problems. The error specifically was: `/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/foo.dir/libfoo.c.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol 'foo_check_context' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`. The compile command did contain `-fPIC`, though, so I'm not sure what the problem was.

Comment: @ijustlovemath Personally I would file that under "don't use cmake".  (The most probable explanation is that one of the several files going into `libfoo` _wasn't_ compiled with `-fPIC` and that has to be cmake's fault.)

Comment: `libfoo.c` is a single file with corresponding header, so I'm not really sure if that's the problem. Regardless of whose fault it was, thank you for this solution!